how to make bluetooth connection for all fragments
  override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        initBtAdapter()
        val pref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
            BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val mac = pref?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, "")
        bluetoothController = BluetoothController(btAdapter)
        try {

            if (item.itemId == R.id.id_color) {
                /*
                activity.let {
                    val intent = Intent(it, ColorGlow::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                 */
                binding.apply {

                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.ColorGlow)
                    }

                //view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.ColorGlow)

               // val i: Intent = Intent(requireContext(), ColorGlow::class.java)
               // startActivity(i)
            }  else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_distance) {
                binding.apply {

                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.GlimpsFragment)
                }
            }
            else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_bt_connect) { // Подключение к ESP32.
                bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this@MainFragment)
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Подключение к маяку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else if (item.itemId == R.id.onOff) {
                if (onOff == false) {
                    onOff = true
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Маяк включен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //btConnection.sendMessage("");
                } else {
                    onOff = false
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Маяк выключен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //btConnection.sendMessage("");
                }
            }   else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_search) {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.listFragment)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Сбой подключения$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

  package com.example.bluetoothmoduletest


import BluetoothController
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.bluetoothmoduletest.databinding.ColorGlowBinding
import com.example.bt_def.BluetoothConstants


class ColorGlow : Fragment(), BluetoothController.Listener {
    private lateinit var bluetoothController: BluetoothController
    private lateinit var btAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ColorGlowBinding



    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = ColorGlowBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    /*
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> finish()
        }
        return true
    }
*/

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initBtAdapter()
        bluetoothController = BluetoothController(btAdapter)
        val pref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
            BluetoothConstants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        val mac = pref?.getString(BluetoothConstants.MAC, "")
        bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this@ColorGlow)
        try {
            binding.apply {
                redButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("R") //RED
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали красный цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    }
                yellowButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("Y") //YELLOW
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали желтый цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()

                }
                greenButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("G") //GREEN
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали зеленый цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                }
                whiteButton.setOnClickListener {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("W") //WHITE
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Вы выбрали белый цвет",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                }
                onOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                    if(isChecked) {
                        bluetoothController.sendMessage("L")
                        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Свет выключен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Сбой подключения$e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }



    }
    private fun initBtAdapter(){
        val bManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        btAdapter = bManager.adapter
    }

I can't transfer the address and bluetooth connection to colorglow. help me transfer the Bluetooth connection without interrupting it when switching to another fragment, help, please.
I can't transfer the address and bluetooth connection to colorglow. help me transfer the Bluetooth connection without interrupting it when switching to another fragment, help, please.

just pass the mac address using Navigation Component to the ColorGlow fragment & use it to make a connection in that fragment.

and how to convey it?

Use Navigation Component Safe Args to pass the Bluetooth device address as a string to the second fragment then, access the remote device using that address & connect to it. Follow the tutorial https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/pass-data
